# Viewing dataset in RStudio shows different number of observations compared to R commands

Tags: r

I am currently studying data science with R. To practice, I am using the `Auto` data of the [ISLR package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ISLR/index.html). However, I am encountering a confusing situation when viewing the data. When I view the dataset `Auto.df` in RStudio, I get the following:

[image]

However, when I use `dim(Auto.df)`, I get the following:

```
> dim(Auto.df)
[1] 392   9
```

And when I use `nrow(Auto.df)`, I get the following:

```
> nrow(Auto.df)
[1] 392
```

And when I use `str(Auto.df)`, I get the following:

```
> str(Auto.df)
'data.frame':   392 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ mpg         : num  18 15 18 16 17 15 14 14 14 15 ...
 $ cylinders   : num  8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 ...
 $ displacement: num  307 350 318 304 302 429 454 440 455 390 ...
 $ horsepower  : num  130 165 150 150 140 198 220 215 225 190 ...
 $ weight      : num  3504 3693 3436 3433 3449 ...
 $ acceleration: num  12 11.5 11 12 10.5 10 9 8.5 10 8.5 ...
 $ year        : num  70 70 70 70 70 70 70 70 70 70 ...
 $ origin      : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ name        : Factor w/ 304 levels "amc ambassador brougham",..: 49 36 231 14 161 141 54 223 241 2 ...
```

And I have the following in my RStudio "Global Environment" tab:

[image]

So why does viewing the dataset in RStudio show 397 rows (observations), whilst everything else says that there are 392 observations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 392 observations in the data. What you are viewing are the rownames of the data. You can set rownames as anything and they do not represent row number in the data.

If you check the rownames of `Auto` dataset you'll realise they are not sequential and some rownames jump by 2. For example, after 32 you don't have 33 but 34. Similarly after 126 there is 128. I don't know why the data is like that but that makes row number at the end to go till 397.

Comment: Oh, wow, you're right, 32 jumps straight to 34.

Comment: In that case, can you please explain how I can half the data? I just want to split the observations into two halves, so that I can compare them. If the numbering of the rows is off, then I don't think I can use subsetting of the data frame based on the rows.

Comment: There are various ways to do that. One way would be to divide number of rows by 2. `n <- round(nrow(Auto)/2);df1 <- Auto[1:n, ];df2 <- Auto[(n+1):nrow(Auto), ]`